# Receive table data from external website in Android using jSoup

Tags: java, android, html, html-table, jsoup

Inside my Android app I want to receive some table data from an external website.

Lets say website page X has this table inside it's HTML:

```
<table summary="Foo" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0"> </table>
```

How would I receive the strings inside all the cells of the second column of the table (top to bottom)?

So far what I have done is the following:

1. Create an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
2. Use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to scrape the external website.

I used the following code inside my AsyncTask:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //table data
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements nextTurns = document.select(":contains(Foo) td:eq(1)");            
        for (Element nextTurn : nextTurns) {
            list.add(nextTurn.text());
        }
```

When running the code it just seems to stop at the `document.select` statement and the GC is going crazy. After a very long time it does get past the `document.select` statement and it does get most of the data correct but it still has random other elements from the website.

I am pretty sure this is completely wrong:

```
Elements nextTurns = document.select(":contains(Foo) td:eq(1)");
```

But I am unsure how to fix it because the table also lacks any ID's. And I find [this page](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) confusing.

How can I fix the select statement and/or for loop so it fills up the ArrayList with data from the second table column?

Edit: by removing `contains(Foo)` it's now really fast so that's 1 problem less. I still need help with traversing the DOM elements to the second column of the table without taking a bunch of random parts of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct selection, guessing based on your post

```
document.select("table[summary=Foo] tr");
```

Loop through the list above, and get the second `<td>` which is at index 1 of the list.